# How would I structure a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have an item table where there is a type column. The values here can be 1, 2, 3, or 0. users have a predefined value, but 0 acts as a global - all users get these items returned.

The main caveat is that an item could be a 3, but also have a 0 record as well, meaning the 3s get one record, the 1s and 2s get the 0 record.

My question is how do i write the query so the 3s don't also get the 0 record?

Comment: show the table structure and people can give suggestions.  it's difficult to make a guess at a linq query without knowing what we would be querying.

Comment: Frédéric gets it. I'm not looking for code, I was looking for an approach. I didn't really have one. Sometimes you just want to toss something at the groupthink and see what falls out. I apologize if I didn't make that clearer. I tried to pare it down to make it simpler to convey. SO and I have a history of not being on the same wavelength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your query simple, you can fetch both records, order them by type, descending, then only take the first one:

- If there is only a type 3 record, it will be returned,
- If there is only a type 0 record, it will be returned,
- If there are both type 3 and type 0 records, the type 3 record will be returned because it will occur first in the result set.